# Display pilot name, number of flights as "Number of Flights", total pay as "Compensation" -- for flights piloted in April of 2017

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to display the name of the pilot from a table named `PILOTS`, show how many flights they have flown from a `DEPARTURES` table in the month of April 2017 and show their compensation by multiplying their number of flights and their compensation per flight.

I have a table named `PILOTS` that has the attribute `pil_flight_pay` and then a table named `FLIGHT`, which has the months for the year 2017. I need to essentially join the 2 tables and count the times APR-2017 shows for each pilot and multiply that by each pilot's flight pay. I know I have to do a subquery but I don't know how and I cant get it to run. I am joining both tables on the `pilot_id` common attribute.

```
SELECT 
  pil_pilotname, 
  COUNT(*) AS "Number of Flights", 
  (COUNT(*) * pil_flight_pay) AS "Compensation"
FROM pilots JOIN departures 
ON (departures.dep_pilot_id = pilots.pil_pilot_id)
WHERE dep_dep_date LIKE '%APR-17%'
GROUP BY pilots.pil_pilotname;
```

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
>   00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

It keeps giving me this error. I want to multiply the flight_per_pay by the times they flew in APR-2017.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `sum()`:

```
SELECT p.pil_pilotname, 
       COUNT(*) AS "Number of Flights", 
       SUM(p.pil_flight_pay) AS "Compensation"
FROM pilots p JOIN
     departures d
     ON d.dep_pilot_id = p.pil_pilot_id
WHERE d.dep_dep_date >= DATE '2017-04-01' AND
      d.dep_dep_date < DATE '2017-05-01'         
GROUP BY p.pil_pilotname;
```

Notes:

- Use table aliases -- abbreviations for the table names.  This makes the query easier to write and to read.
- Qualify all column names so you -- and anyone else reading the query -- know where the columns come from.
- Don't use string functions on dates.
- Use `DATE` to introduce date constants.

Comment: pil_flight_pay is a column in the table PILOTS.

Comment: and using date filtering as in this answer is important to be able to exploit the index on `dep_dep_date` column if exists any @giowest .